# Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect()

Tags: php

Estoy haciendo unas paginas web por refrescar conocimiento y por hobbie, sin embargo, cuando he copiado todos los archivos de mi pc (windows 7) donde hacía pruebas hacia un servidor linux centos me muestra el error siguiente:

Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect() in /var/www/html/Outsourcing/conecta_mysql.php on line 11

No está por demás indicar que en mi ambiente de pruebas (mi PC) funciona, y es por eso que lo subi al linux.

Mi php.ini tiene la siguiente info:

Build Date:         Mar 7 2018 13:35:39
Server API:         Apache 2.0 Handler
Virtual Directory Support:  disabled
Configuration File (php.ini): Path  /etc
Loaded Configuration File:  /etc/php.ini

Version:

[root@localhost ~]# php -v
PHP 5.4.16 (cli) (built: Mar  7 2018 13:34:47) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies

Espero me puedan ayudar.

Gracias.

Comment: Esto puede ocurrir porque no tengas instalada/activada la extensión de MySQLi en tu servidor. Comprueba la configuración de PHP y las extensiones activas.

Answer (score 1):

Hola amigo espero que estés muy bien, a mi esto me ocurrió porque en mi archivo "php.ini" tenía una línea de extensión comentada, te ayudaré, lo primero que harás será entrar a la siguiente ruta a través de la terminal:

```
cd /etc/php/7.0/apache2
```

Ya nos encontramos en la carpeta de apache llamada "apache2" ahora bien, debemos darle permisos al archivo llamado "php.ini" que está en la carpeta mencionada anteriormente para poder modificar y guardar los cambios que haremos más adelante, basta con colocar en la terminal:

```
sudo chown 777 php.ini
```

Y listo, ya podrás modificar y guardar, lo que sigue es hacer lo siguiente, abrirás el archivo "php.ini" de la siguiente manera:

```
nano php.ini
```

Se te abrirá el documento y lo que harás será presionar la combinación de teclas CTRL + W y se te abrirá un buscador (una barrita blanca en la terminal), allí escribirás:

```
;extension=mysqli
```

Como ves antes de la palabra "extension" existe un punto y coma **;** eso significa que esa línea dentro de nuestro archivo "php.ini" está comentada, debemos descomentarla, es decir, debemos quitar el **;** de allí, nos quedaría algo así:

```
extension=mysqli
```

Apretamos CTRL + O para guardar, nos dirá que si estamos seguros, decimos que si y luego salimos con CTRL + X, lo último que haremos será reiniciar apache y esto se logra con este comando:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Y listo hermanito, ya debería estar todo listo :D espero que mi respuesta te haya ayudado.

Comment: Gracias Alfredo por tu gentil ayuda, sin embargo, en mi archivo php.ini no tengo esa linea, la aumenté pero con el mismo resultado y error.

Comment: Alfredo amigo gracias, logré resolverlo con: yum install php-mysqli

Comment: Siempre a su orden hermano, me alegra que haya resuelto el problema, muchos éxitos :D

Comment: Si es un servidor Debian/Ubuntu (o similar): apt install php-mysql